# Remover estilos de un select en materialize

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

tengo un formulario el cual necesito que al seleccionar una opcion de un select me aparezca en el otro select diferentes items al seleccionar el primer select, me funciona pero al usar materializecss.com como framework, no me lo muestra, como puedo hacer para quitar los estilos del select en materializecss.com ???

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar la Clase por defecto de Materialize "**browser-default**".

ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="browser-default"/>
```

Documentacion Oficial: [Aqui](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html#browser-default)

Comment: Trate de hacerlo pero no me funciono nose porque :(

Answer (score 1):

Genera una **clase** y se la agregas al `select` y le colocas !important al final ejemplio

```
.class{
  color: #000000 !important
}
```

aqui deberia tomar el color negro

Comment: Pero eso no le cambiaria los estilos de materializecss.com

Comment: Los estilos de las clases no lo puedes cambiar solo sobrescribir las clases que te trae materialize